# Magento Slider installation not working

Tags: magento

Hi i have installed this slider on my magento store. i just bought from here.
[Mag](http://www.magpassion.com/magento-product-carousel-extension.html)
But after installing, drop down menu of the website stopped working plus banner slider. Also the new slider is not showing at all. I tried to contact the Mag seller but they are not responding at all. It seems javascript issue. Any hints are tips much appreciated. thanks

Comment: What does the browser console say?

Comment: if we install script through magento connect, few things stopped working as below
1) drop down menu at top stopped working
2) main top banner at home page stopped working
3) layout near feature listing showing error
4) products showing in rows were pushing one box below
5) zoom in image stopped working.

As I know bit of php and js, I guess its java script which conflicts with your new files or html is corrupting with template installed.
We installed magento 1.9.1 version

Comment: we are using this template on our site. http://themeforest.net/item/shopper-magento-theme-responsive-retina-ready/full_screen_preview/3139960

Comment: If you use Chrome or Firefox on the page, press Ctrl+Shift+J. A window should appear. Are there any messages (e.g. in red)?

Comment: no if press ctrl shift j and then i can't see any error message. Also i found if we click setting in admin section then this error message comes (instead of showing default template to be selected).  -------------------------------- 404 Error Page not found.

Answer (score 0):

The Problems that you might have encountered may be

1. jQuery/javascript error which make your other script stopped. For this like `kaska` said above` check for any error in your browser
   console.

   2. Bring all the template, layout and skin files by the module under `<Your_package>/<Your_Theme>`. (Search for the files the module
      has
      inserted, few modules inserts their template,layout and skin file under `<default_package>/<default_theme>` and if your active package and active there is other than this you would encounter issues)

And that is all i can say for now, until you provide more info

Comment: yeah you are right. It seems javascript because all javascript stuff stopped working. but it's too much, looking for some easy fix?